# public cert is not picked from keystore provided in wso2 micro integrator

Tags: wso2, mtls, wso2-micro-integrator

I have created a MI project using Hello World Docker template using [Integration Studio 7.2.0](https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/). I want to setup mTLS for the service. I have configured the keystore like below.

deployment.toml

```
[keystore.tls]
file_name = "interceptor.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"
alias = "interceptor"
key_password = "wso2carbon"

[truststore]
file_name = "interceptor.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"
alias = "mg"
algorithm="AES"
```

`interceptor.jks` contains client cert with alias `mg` and privateKey with alias `interceptor`. This service is invoked using cURL as below.

```
curl --cacert interceptor.pem --cert mg.pem --key mg.key  "https://xml-interceptor:8253/api/v1/handle-request" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "accept: application/json" -d '{"requestBody": "eyJuYW1lIjoiVGhlIFByaXNvbmVyIn0="}' -v
```

And it fails. While it is successful with `-k` option I noticed that the cert received to the client is below and not the one I configured in `deployment.toml`

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=Mountain View; O=WSO2; OU=WSO2; CN=localhost
*  start date: Oct 23 07:30:43 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 25 07:30:43 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; ST=CA; L=Mountain View; O=WSO2; OU=WSO2; CN=localhost
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> POST /api/v1/handle-request HTTP/1.1
```

I get this in Micro Integrator logs,

```
[2022-06-15 13:38:29,417]  WARN {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

Seems it is unable to read the cert I configured. Any idea how to sort out this issue?

I have already tried importing the privateKey to `wso2carbon.jks` as well.

Comment: Which micro integrator version are you using? You can see concrete version in startup logs.

Comment: @usuario, It is Micro Integrator Server 1.2.0

Comment: This specific configuration changes a lot between versions. Check their latest [reference](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/mi-setup/security/configuring_keystores). I believe the problem is the toml key. If you are using an updated server you need to use `keystore.primary` instead of `keystore.tls`. You also need to provide full path to the jks file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it seems the keystore is not getting updated.

You can build the docker image from the Integration Studio as specified in here[1].

Then you can mount the new keystore to the MI container [2].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/create-docker-project/#build-and-push-docker-images

[2] - https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume

Comment: Thanks! this worked. But the actual issue still exists when running it inside the Integration Studio